# how to install Mosquitto MQTT on linux server

Tags: linux, installation, mqtt, mosquitto

I have to install mosquitto MQTT on Linux server. I searched  on internet and found most of the documents explain how to install in on Linux OS or windows OS. My ask is how to install it in Linux server. Which directory, I need to use and how to do?

Comment: We really can't answer this at as it stands, without knowing what Linux Distribution you are using, or if you want to build it from source

Comment: Your question made me realize I missed it. Linux distribution is centOS7.

Comment: Have you tried `yum install mosquitto`?

Comment: I installed mosquitto, through 'snap install mosquitto' given in  Mosquito MQTT Download page. When I do snap list in usr/bin diectory, I see mosquitto installed. But where are mosquitto files in linux, as I will need its .conf  file.

Comment: The config file will probably either be in `/etc/mosquitto` or possibly under the `~/snap` directory

Answer (score 1):

Linux OS and Linux Server are two similar things. At least on this level of needs which is just installing an application.

At the first I'd recommend you to read some Linux tutorial, at first glance something like [this](https://www.guru99.com/unix-linux-tutorial.html). There you get the knowledge that installing programs into Linux quite depends on Linux distribution you currently use. And, when you are not compiling the source code of a program, you can not usually affect the destination directory - Linux has the different philosophy of folders than Windows and usually you don't install the program to one directory in some root but to many of them (bin, lib, share, ...). But in minority also some installers exists and you can affect the top level destination directory using them. I am not sure what kind of attitude chose Mosquito MQTT.

At the second I've read the [Mosquito MQTT Download page](https://mosquitto.org/download/) and it seems that the easiest way ( ! but I am not sure if the desired in your company environment ! ) is to install `snap` via the packaging system of your Linux distribution and just run the recommended `snap install mosquitto`. And if the snap package is build reasonably, you will have your application installed and ready to run and configure.

Comment: No need for snap, pretty much all the major distro's include a version of mosquitto in their standard packages, it might not be the most up to date, but it's there.

Comment: I installed mosquitto, through 'snap install mosquitto' given in  Mosquito MQTT Download page. When I do snap list in usr/bin diectory, I see mosquitto installed. But where are mosquitto files in linux, as I will need its .conf  file. see the server logs 'code'[root@host bin]# snap list
Name       Version   Rev    Tracking       Publisher   Notes
core18     20211015  2246   latest/stable  canonical*  base
mosquitto  2.0.13    675    latest/stable  mosquitto*  -
snapd      2.52.1    13640  latest/stable  canonical*  snapd
'code'